# Cannot kill `grep --color=auto` process in terminal

Tags: process, kill

I use `ps aux | grep -i apt` to find the process and get:

```
antonio  19070  0.0  0.0  14424  1096 pts/0    S+   07:41   0:00 grep --color=auto -i apt
```

Commands such as `sudo kill -9 14424` or any other number (it has changed over the last 12 hours) all give me a return of "no such process."

Answer (score 4):

Read the results carefully, you are detecting your `grep apt` command, which is gone by the time you type the next command..

Either use `pgrep apt` (`man pgrep`), or modify your search string so it's no longer a match for the string "`apt`", e.g. `grep '[a]pt'`.

Comment: I appreciate this. Sorry to be that guy but I tried pgrep apt and nothing was returned. ps aux | grep '[a]pt just gave me a command prompt without anything in front of it.

Comment: @AntonioFerraroBruno there was a missing closing quote in the command - it should be `grep '[a]pt'`

Comment: Also, if your 'grep' command does not detect any other process besides itself, that means that no 'apt' process is currently running.

Answer (score 3):

```
ps aux | grep -i apt
```

will return any process that has `apt` in the result returned by `ps`. It can be in the command, as in `grep -i apt`

So basically, your command returns only one result, which is... itself. When you try to kill it, it has already finished, so the process has gone.